# Python Genetic Algorithm: Modifying Class for Gender Differentiation

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, genetic-algorithm

I am experimenting with python about genetic algorithm. In other words, I want to make a program to simulate random process and control come parts (like experiment) to play around with variables and outcomes.

So far, with help from a mate, I have devised until this set of codes:

```
import random
import string

num_rats = 20
min_offspring = 5
max_offspring = 10
weight_min = 5
weight_max = 10
mutation_chance_rate = 10  # %
mutation_weight_decrease = 20  # %
generations = 20
multiplier = 1.1

alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
def random_name():
    #Generates random chars for rat names.
    return ''.join(random.choices(alphabet, k=5))

def print_population(population):
    for i, r in enumerate(population):
        print(f'no. {i+1:02d}, name: {r.name}, weight: {r.weight}')

class Rat: 
    def __init__(self, name, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight

def breeding(p1, p2):
    """
    Create offsprings from parents p1 and p2.
    Randomize number of offsprings and weight is based on parents weight.
    """
    offspring = []
    w1 = p1.weight
    w2 = p2.weight
    meanw = ((w1+w2)/2) * multiplier

number_offspring = random.randint(min_offspring, max_offspring)
for _ in range(1, number_offspring + 1):
    name = random_name()
    weight = meanw
    offspring.append(Rat(name, weight))  # Create Rat object as new pop
return offspring

def cut_offspring_population(population):
    #population is a list of rats.
    #Cut offsprings to orignal number of rats, preserve heavier rats.
    new_population = sorted(population, key=lambda x: x.weight, reverse=True)  # sort rats weights descending
    random.shuffle(new_population)
    return new_population[0:num_rats]# Cutoff


def negative_mutation(population):
    #10% chance of mutation that decreases weight by 20%.
    new_population = []
    for p in population:
        current_name = p.name
        current_weight = p.weight
        if random.randint(1, 100) <= mutation_chance_rate:
            current_weight = current_weight * (100 - mutation_weight_decrease) / 100
        new_population.append(Rat(current_name, current_weight))
        else:
            new_population.append(Rat(current_name, current_weight))
    return new_population

def original_rats():
    orig_rats = []
    for _ in range(num_rats):
        weight = random.uniform(weight_min, weight_max)
        orig_rats.append(Rat(random_name(), weight))
    return orig_rats

def main():
    # (1) Create rats
    tmp_rats = original_rats().copy()
    for i in range(1, generations + 1):
        # (2) Breeding
        new_offsprings = []
        while tmp_rats:
            # Select 2 rats as parents.
            new_offsprings = new_offsprings + breeding(tmp_rats.pop(), tmp_rats.pop())
        # (3) Mutation
        mutated_pop = negative_mutation(new_offsprings)
        # (4) Reduce population.
        reduced_pop = cut_offspring_population(mutated_pop)
        print(f'gen: {i}')
        #print_population(reduced_pop)
        tmp_rats = reduced_pop  # for next gen
        # Print average.
        rat_weight_total = []
        for p in tmp_rats:  # [Rat('name', weight), Rat('name', weight) ...]
            rat_weight_total.append(p.weight)
        all_weight = sum(rat_weight_total) / len(rat_weight_total)
        print(f'average weight: {all_weight:0.2f}')  # :0.2f is up to 2 decimal places

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

To explain this long code, I am simulating rat reproduction and controlling its population to create superior (in my case, heavier) rats at the end. In specific, I want to have starting population of rats, randomly pair two for reproduction (in which offspring will have average weight of two parent rats) and control offspring population and so on. In simple words, I will have x population of rats (initial and constant), create offsprings, list them by weight, kill from the bottom (lightest rats) to lower the offspring population == initial population and repeat the process to eventually create heavier rats.

Now, I want to make this program more real-life reflective by modifying class Rat to be gender reflective.

Instead of having name and weight for rat (a unisex rat), I would like to have 2 different classes for Rat (one class for male and one for female). Since the initial and constant population is 20 rats, it would thus be 10 male and 10 female rats. To elaborate, if my original set of codes took 20 parent rats (gender-indifferent) and took random 2 to reproduce (reduce population to constant and repeat), I would want a modified set of codes that would assume 10 female 10 male populated rat (20 total) and take random rat from EACH gender class, breed and put offsprings differentiated by gender (so male offspring goes back to male class and female organized to female class). Then the population would be reduced to 10 heaviest male and 10 heavies female rats and the process is repeated.

After writing this question, I noticed that the codes and writings are very long and tedious. Although this might be out of interest or tedious, a little help would be genuinely appreciated. Please let me know for any clarifications.

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: you don't need to explain the long code, you need to provide a [mre] and why have you tagged this with both python3 and python2? only use those tags if question is version specific and then tag that specific version only, but in this case it doesn't seem you need either of those tags (and note that you can [edit] your question to add the info and remove those tags)

Comment: I've edited the tags but I use the 3.n version so I left the tag for that one. For the code, I figured explaining beforehand rather than having bits and needing to explain later would be better. If you have a problem with this, I will be more than willing to edit it out.

Comment: you don't need to explain in bits, just have one short [mre] (meaning it can be copy-pasted and work and reproduce the problem and it is extremely minimal) and explain that or more of explain what it is supposed to do, what is the input and then the expected output